# Magento 2 - Get product atrribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I'm trying to get a product attribute on the product listing page, on `title.phtml`.

I've tried quite a few different methods found through googling but nothing seems to be working.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' . $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
    <div class="page-title-wrapper<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo $cssClass; ?>">
        <h1 class="page-title"
            <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $block->getId(); ?>" <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
                aria-labelledby="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria(); ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $title ?>
        </h1>
        testing:
        <?php
        $attr = $block->getData('style_general');
        echo $attr;
        ?>
        <?php echo $block->getStyle_general(); ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Testing**:

```
$attr = $block->getData('style_general');
echo $attr;
```

is the current method I'm trying, but it nothing is showing up...

Comment: You want to get custom attribute on product listing `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml`?. I don't know why you want to get custom attribute in `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\title.phtml`

Comment: because I want to put a 'sub title' under the title

Comment: Could you please accept the answer that has worked for you as the correct one?

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194014/add-custom-attribute-below-title-in-magento-2-1 or share which way has worked for you. Please, share if you solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add Below code in your `list.phtml` file in Magento 2. Set your Attribute code in attribute name. After this you will get attribute label or value.

```
$attr = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('Yourattributecode')->getOptions();
foreach ($attr as $attrColor) {
    if ($attrColor->getValue()) {
        echo $attrColor->getLabel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can get custom attributes with `$_product->getData('custom_attribute');`, depending on which Interceptor is used right now.

For example, you can't call your custom attribute when showing Upselling products, since the Interceptor doesn't have access to it.

But that's not all. If you are using a Dropdown field, or a Multiselect, you will get the ID based of the selected value as a string back. In order to get the correct labels for those selected strings you need to the following:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

Just replace `your_attribute_code` with whatever your attribute is named.