# How to get attribute value in magento 2.0.6 product view and list page

Tags: product, product-attribute, magento-2.0.6

How to get product attribute value in magento 2.0.6 product view page and list page

Comment: [CheckLink.](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124093/magento-2-get-product-atrribute/124511#124511) -  Check Above Link Sure help you to Get attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In product view page you can get like this:

```
$this->getProduct()->getId();
$this->getProduct()->getName();
```

You can get custom attribute like this:

```
$attribute = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_id');
if ($attribute)
{
    $brick_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($this->getProduct());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply  i am getting below error Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on a non-object in view.phtml

Comment: this code is work only in magento 2 product view page.

Comment: i am using magento 2.0.6 is it work?

Comment: using this  $_attributeValue =$product->getResource()->getAttribute('test_attrivute ')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); i am getting  YES/NO as text how can get value like 1/0

Comment: yes. i have used above code in my store.