# Add custom attribute below title in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I have checked all of other answers that have been accepted but can't seem to get this working correctly. I have created the custom attribute and set it up to display on the frontend. It is showing up fine on the spec table tab but I am also trying to add it to right below the title.

I found the `title.phtml` file and tested first with a test h2 tag and after clearing cache and deleting var folder content confirmed it displays on the front end, but when I try the code the title and my h2 addition dis-appears.

I've tried reading the dev docs and am stuck at this point. I'm not a certified developer or anything clearly, so please be kind in your criticisms of my attempt. Thanks for any help in advance I truly appreciate it and will stop banging my head against my monitor if you can solve this :)

The code below is pulled from the file in `vendor\your_theme\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\title.phtml` and my addition to the code is within the h2 tag

```
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $cssClass; ?>">
<h1 class="page-title"
    <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getId();?>" <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
        aria-labelledby="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria(); ?>"
    <?php endif; ?>>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title ?>
</h1>
<h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?></h2>

<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found the correct file which is using for Managing the Page Main title. 
In file `templates\html\title.phtml` as you can see the below function to add other child blocks using `layout.xml

getChildHtml(); ?>

To add Subtitle on Product Page add the below code `catalog_product_view.xml` in your current theme.

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.subtitle" template="product/view/subtitle.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Create a new file `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/subtitle.phtml` in your current theme directory and place the below code:

```
<h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct()); ?></h2>
```

Clear the cache and subtitle will work fine.

Comment: Thanks man! Super easy and it works no problem. Really appreciate it

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, I tried and it display nothing. Do I have to add something additionally in the `title.phtml`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call custom phtml file below title by xml, follow below directory to open xml file and put below code.

```
app/desigin/frontend/your_theme/module_theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml 

    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="subtitle" template="product/view/subtitle.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
```

get subtitle attribute in subtitle.phtml.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
<h1 class="page-title">
<?php echo $product->getSubTitle(); ?>
<h1>
```